# How to return value of ternary operator in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, ternary-operator

I have this php code in CodeIgniter and having this code in controller side but i can't get my actual result 'Available' which should come according to this ternary operator code. In this code the result returns echo in the jquery code in view page. Currently it is returning only true part of the condition when condition is false it also returns true part instead of false part.

```
    $data['1']['0']['available']= 0 to 10; 
echo "<div class='services'>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                            <h3 class='media-heading'>Check avability</h3>
                            <div class='table-responsive'>
                                <table class='table'>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr><th>Sr.no</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>
                                        <tr><td>1</td>
                                        <td>Delux</td>";
                                            echo ($data['1']['0']['available'] < 10) ? '<td>Available</td>': '<td>Not Available</td>' ;
                                        echo"<td>".$data['1']['0']['available']."</td>
                                        <td><button class='btn btn-success'>Book Now</button></td>"; echo "</tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>";
```

Comment: this question was asked before also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working fine here

For `not available`

```
$data['1']['0']['available'] = 14;
echo ($data['1']['0']['available'] < 10) ? '<td>Available</td>': '<td> Not Available</td>' ;
```

prints as `Not Available`

[DEMO](https://eval.in/480250)

For `available`

```
$data['1']['0']['available'] = 4;
echo ($data['1']['0']['available'] < 10) ? '<td>Available</td>': '<td> Not Available</td>' ;
```

prints as `Available`

[DEMO](https://eval.in/480254)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
$data['1']['0']['available']=$any_numeric_value ; 
echo "<div class='services'>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                            <h3 class='media-heading'>Check avability</h3>
                            <div class='table-responsive'>
                                <table class='table'>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr><th>Sr.no</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>
                                        <tr><td>1</td>
                                        <td>Delux</td>".(($data['1']['0']['available'] < 10) ? '<td>Available</td>': '<td>Not Available</td>' ).
                                        "<td>".$data['1']['0']['available']."</td>
                                        <td><button class='btn btn-success'>Book Now</button></td></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>";
                  ?>
```

Comment: it could be done in only one echo statement for $any_numeric_value=5 prints "Available" and for $any_numeric_value=25 prints "Not Available"

Comment: This code is not working in my controller because $data['1']['0']['available'] comes dynamically from database and the datatype of that array is string. It works if i put int($data['1']['0']['available']).

Comment: as i checked its working fine i assigned  $data['1']['0']['available']=array_rand(array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','15','20','27','433','342','343243')); and i got its working

Comment: please provide me the array that you are getting from database

Answer (score 0):

I think the array returns string value. First check that array returns string or integer. If returns string then convert it into integer then try. I hope this will works.